# How to call api using savon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, servicenow

I am using savon gem in my rails application for calling service_now api. I want to call the api for update description. I have url for updating

```
https://servicenow.com/xyzlist?JSONv2&sysparm_query=number='xyz123'&sysparm_action=update&displayvalue=true

body "comments":"updated description"
```

Above is working perfectly in postmen. But how can i pass this params into my local rails application for updating

I am using below code for creating tickets.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://servicenow.com/xyzlist.do?WSDL",basic_auth: ['xyz', 'abc'], log: true, log_level: :debug, pretty_print_xml: true)

response =  client.call(:insert, message: params)
```

Can you please anyone help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to two different APIs in your example code: JSONv2 and SOAP.

Two questions: 1) do you need to use SOAP, or can you use REST instead? (Rails should support this without issue) and 2) what version of ServiceNow are you using? If you're running Geneva or later and you're able to use REST, you should be using the REST Table API for new integrations, not JSONv2.

See the documentation here for examples:

https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=istanbul&id=r_TableAPI-PUT